# JMESPath propagating outer field to dicts in list

Tags: python, json, jmespath

I'm trying to write JMESPath for following structure:

```
{
    "example": [
        {
            "field": "value",
            "lst": [
                {
                    "inner_field": "fvalue"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
[
    {
        "inner_field": "fvalue",
        "field": "value"
    }
]
```

With `field` being inserted into all dictionaries in `lst`.
I'm aware of things like:

```
example[*].{field: field, lst: lst}
```

But is there a way to assign `field` for each element in `lst`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were expecting?

```
example[*].{field: field,inner_field: lst[0].inner_field}
```